# How can i go to storyboard from xib

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode5, xib

i am using both storyboard and xib in my project and i want to go xib files from storyboard but can't reverse it. so how i go to storyboard from xib files. thnx in advance.
storyboard to xib:

```
Dashboard1ViewController *tempView = [[Dashboard1ViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"Dashboard1ViewController" bundle:nil];
    tempView.passemail = [matches valueForKey:@"email"];
    [self.view addSubview:tempView.view];
```

it works fine but  xib to storyboard i have used this code

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"loginUI" bundle:nil];
login2ViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login2"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

but it is not working.

Comment: please check out this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190680/from-xib-to-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

the following method is working for me. make sure that your identifier is correct

```
YourViewController *urViewController = (YourViewController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil]     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardID"];
[self presentViewController:urViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Debug and find whether ViewController instance is created.Also check your storyboard is added in bundle resource.

Comment: there is no difference between two options you mentioned.

Comment: Storyboard is added in bundle resource still app crashin

Comment: @mustafabesnili just for understanding i mentioned ,as you said i removed

Comment: @karthikPrabhu still it is not working... can u please tell me what should i do?

Comment: did you debugged and find where its crashing ?

Comment: yes.. it is crashing when i click on the xib's button to go storyboard.

Comment: put a break point and check which line its crashing and paste the error

Comment: Attempt to present <SignupViewController: 0x8bdd830> on <Dashboard1ViewController: 0x8cae040> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy . Are you using navigationController? Where you initialised ?paste your code

Comment: UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"loginUI" bundle:nil];
   SignupViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignupView"];
    
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:vc];

Comment: You have to learn basics first , please check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Change `nil` to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"loginUI" 
                                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```